# What does the "not" method do?

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm confused by this code (from Chris Pine's Learn to Program, chapter 8: Writing Your Own Methods).

```
goodAnswer = false
while (not goodAnswer)
  puts 'Do you like eating chimichangas?'
  answer = gets.chomp.downcase
  if (answer == 'yes' or answer == 'no')
    goodAnswer = true
  else
    puts 'Please answer "yes" or "no".'
  end
end
```

I'm confused specifically by the method `not`. I would think that it means "(while) variable(goodAnswer) is (not) false (i.e., true), continue this loop". But exactly the opposite occurs: the loop breaks as soon as variable (`goodAnswer`) is true.

So I'm curious, what the heck does the `not` function do? I can't find a definition for it anywhere, and this is the only example I can find of its use.

Comment: http://www.theodorenguyen-cao.com/2008/03/29/ruby-versus-not-operator/#.Uk2bPSS4J2A

Comment: It really is a logical `not`. So `not false` is `true` and `not true` is false. If you think you're seeing something different, there's another problem somewhere. I ran your example and it worked as expected. As @Zabba points out, you may have to be concerned with operator precedence in expressions. But in your example, it's very simple.

Comment: `not` returns the opposite of the variable after it. So as long as `goodAnswer` is false, `not goodAnswer` is true. Once `goodAnswer` becomes true, then `not goodAnswer` becomes false. If you read it like plain English, it actually makes sense.

Comment: You could actually rewrite the loop as `until goodAnswer`

Comment: Think of it this way: `while(not goodAnswer)` is the same as `while(goodAnswer == false)`.  Also, @p11y has a good point.  I try to use `unless` instead of `not` whereever I can.  Other points: 1) putting a capital letter in a variable name brands you a rookie.  Use `good_answer`. (Camelcase is reserved for class names.)  2) `unless good_answer` is the same thing as `unless good_answer==true`. 3) you could also use `while (!good_answer)`.

Answer (score 2):

It means roughly what it says:

"While it's not a good answer"

(i.e., while `goodAnswer` is false).

Answer (score 1):

First: `not` is *not* a method, it’s a keyword. [The docs](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000027) explain what it is:

> #### `not`
>
> Boolean negation.
>
> ```
> not true    # false
> not 10      # false
> not false   # true
> ```
>
> Similar in effect to the negating bang (`!`), but has lower precedence:
>
> ```
> not 3 == 4  # true; interpreted as not (3 == 4)
> !3 == 4     # false; interpreted as (!3) == 4, i.e., false == 4
> ```
>
> (The unary `!` also differs in that it can be overridden.)

Comment: This is the answer you want to read. And, btw., though unary `!` can be overriden, don't you please ever do it!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are assuming it to be opposite of what it is.

`while (goodAnswer)`  => will run the loop while `goodAnswer` is True

so naturally

`while (not goodAnswer)`  => will run the loop while `goodAnswer` is `false`, and it will stop as soon as it turns `true`.

Comment: while (goodAnswer) runs the loop *while* goodAnswer is true, not *until* it's true.